# Impossible to find consistent, non redudant data model for XOR-relationship

Tags: oracle, database-design, data-modeling, foreign-key-relationship, xor

In my data model I have a XOR / mutually exclusive / arc relationship. I found some documentation how to model this kind of relationship (e.g. http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server)

**.) Model Approach**

```
Person (PersonID*, PersonTypeID)
Student (PersonID*, PersonTypeID=1, EnrollmentDate) --is a person
Teacher (PersonID*, PersonTypeID=2, HireDate) --is a person
```

Defining unique key constraints on PersonID+PersonTypeID I can create foreign key constraints on both columns PersonID+PersonTypeID to ensure the XOR.

I like that approach, because I don't need any triggers or check constraints.

**.) Problem**

In my case I have one level more, let's say a Super_Person, where the PersonTypeID is stored:

```
Super_Person (Super_Person_ID*, PersonTypeID)
Person (PersonID*, PersonTypeID (???), Super_Person_ID) --is a Super_Person
Student (PersonID*, PersonTypeID=1, EnrollmentDate) --is a person
Teacher (PersonID*, PersonTypeID=2, HireDate) --is a person
```

To create the foreign key constraints (Student-Person and Teacher-Person) I need the PersonTypeID in the Person table. But the PersonTypeID actually is stored in Super_Person. So a trigger is needed to propagate the PersonTypeID from Super_Person to Person, which I don't want to do because it's redundant information.

Any suggestions how to model that nicely? Thanks!

Comment: "I don't want to do because it's redundant information." - but then so are the constant values in `Student` and `Teacher`. Either you're happy to store redundant information to allow constraints to be enforced or you're not.

Comment: Well if both is not possible in general then that's ok for me and I have to decide. But maybe there is another approach I don't know or a best practise for that kind of relationships.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Because different ones let you write different constraints without triggers.

Comment: I am using Oracle 12c

Comment: Please add Oracle as a tag. PS you must use *@name* for *name* to be notified of your comment if they are neither the only commenter nor the poster. (I just happened by.)